# Multiple connect to each other trials in C sockets

Tags: c, sockets

I have 2 socket servers that just need to try to connect to each other multiple times. What I did was created 2 sockets s1 and s2. Binded s1 to certain port and address. 
Then inside while(num_trials)<200 loop, I run connect() with s1 to server 2. When I run the 2 programs,first server loops and shows that it is trying but they don't connect to each other.Second server meanwhile enters the loop 1 time and just waits.

I tried to close the s1 socket everytime - that makes the 2 server to loop too - but still they don't connect to each other. I am not sure if I am missing some details.I cannot use select and this is not the case of accepting multiple client connections. Is there any better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sockets are blocking by default. When you perform any operation on it, it will block until the operation has finished. Hence you need to make your socket non-blocking or use [select](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) (or other async mechanism).

Another alternative, as mentioned by [maheshgupta024](https://stackoverflow.com/users/503129/maheshgupta024), is to split the operations in different threads. E.g: server runs in the main thread, and client in a secondary thread.

Comment: If anyone interested this is what I was looking for: http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPConnectionEstablishmentProcessTheThreeWayHandsh-4.htm - Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

How bout creating two threads and connecting each other.. one should be listnening and other should be connecting for one port. 
i.e say S1 is listening to port 1000 then S2 should connect to 1000
and S2 should listen on 2000 and S1 should connect to 2000.